# Excel - Renaming and SUM - Manipulating values automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I've got the following problem to solve with an excel table:

Column A contains country names and column B, values, as the example below shows.
There are some names in column A that came with aditional words added to it, so i need them to be treated like an unique country other columns.

Follows an example:

```
            A           |     B
------------------------------------
      Country Name      |   Number
------------------------------------
ITALY (MOBILE)          |    100
PORTUGAL (MOBILE)       |    180
UNITED KINGDOM (MOBILE) |    160
ARGENTINA BUA           |    120
FRANCE MOBILE ORANGE    |    100
CHINA (MOBILE)          |    100
ITALY                   |    93
SPAIN (MOBILE)          |    90
PORTUGAL                |    85
GERMANY (MOBILE)        |    75
UNITED KINGDOM          |    10
GERMANY                 |    70
ECUADOR (MOBILE)        |    55
```

The exit could be a table like the following, in the same worksheet, to columns D and E, for example.
It would sum countries values and show them as the right unique country name (The right name would be the first one that shows up, before the "(", and without the values between "()" ).

```
            A           |     B
------------------------------------
ITALY                   |    193
PORTUGAL                |    265
UNITED KINGDOM          |    170
GERMANY                 |    145
ARGENTINA               |    120
FRANCE MOBILE ORANGE    |    100
CHINA                   |    100
SPAIN                   |     90
ECUADOR                 |     55
```

Is it easier using VBA?

Thanks, guys!

Comment: And how do I use TRIM to sum the values that are from the same country?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. Label column C Country (or whatever you need) and write this formula in column C:

   =SUBSTITUTE(A2," (MOBILE)","")
2. Create a pivot table on columns A through C, with column C as your row labels and the sum of column B as your values.

@pnuts makes a good point below. I'd use this formula instead in part 1:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(REPLACE(A2,FIND("(",A2),FIND(")",A2)-FIND("(",A2)+1,"")),A2)
```

Comment: If there are no parentheses, then how are you identifying where you need to find and replace?

Comment: What are you replacing if you cannot find it using the existence of the parentheses?

Comment: We are misunderstanding each other. I see now what you meant by my function failing when there are no parentheses and I have fixed it above using the `IFERROR` function. I thought you were objecting to identifying the excess text by its presence between parentheses.